# Not performing a select when a condition is not satisfied

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to perform a `SELECT` only when a condition is satisfied.

So far, the most I've come up with is the following:

```
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN country = 'Germany'
            THEN (SELECT population)
       END
FROM table;
```

However, the query returns an empty column named "case", as shown in the image:

[image: Empty column called "case"]

Note that I don't want to make the field false or null, **I don't even want this column to appear in the resulting table**, as I need to use this same query for different databases. For example, the same query that I will use in the database "Germany", where the column "population" exists, should also be used in the database "Italy", where the column "population" does not even exist.

In other words:

- If the country is "Germany", I would like to return "id" and "population".
- Else, I would like to return only "id".

Note: It needs to be the same query. There is no possibility for me to make a different query for each country.

Comment: This is how SQL works, you can't have a dynamic number of columns. By the way, the SELECT is obsolete, you can leave it our. Just like ( and ).

Comment: You can't have dynamically appearing columns. Considering that most tables have more than 1 record in them, what sense would SQL like this even mean? If `country` is `germany` for one record and `country` was `poland` for a second record... would this column appear or disappear. What you want is `SELECT id, CASE WHEN country='Germany' THEN population END as german_population FROM yourtable` which will only populate that new column with a non-null value if the `country` for the record is `Germany`.

Comment: I may not have made myself clear. I have two tables:

1) Table "Germany", with columns "Id" and "Population";
2) Table "Italy", with column "Id".

They are not two records in the same table, but two different tables. Is it still impossible to carry out the query the way I intended?

Comment: No, one single query will always result in in a fixed number of columns in the result set. Always. And Yes, some columns (or records) can return a NULL

Comment: *"Is it still impossible to carry out the query the way I intended?"* No. It is not possible. We define a result set using SQL as the language and that result set's schema is not malleable based on the data that it may contain. Furthermore, having a table that holds a single record, and having one table per country... it's just a complete misunderstanding of databases to begin with. One should have a `country` table with a row for each country. You are designing a bit of a mess, I'm afraid.

Comment: Database normalization (3NF most of the time) might be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Unrelated, but:`(SELECT population)` can be simplified to `population`

Comment: @JNevill This was just an example, I'm not dealing with tables with just one record. The real situation is that of different clients that have, in theory, tables with the same columns. But one client decided to add a new column, which basically resulted in my questioning.

Comment: @MatheusReis Gotcha. That makes sense. You would either have to do `SELECT *` and just pull back all columns or handle the writing of the SQL that is being submitted in a separate language (including a stored procedure). Like in python: `sql = 'SELECT id, population FROM germantable;' If country='germany' Else 'SELECT id FROM francetable;'` And then submit the resulting sql to the database. Essentially dynamically writing your sql statement and executing.